# How to download a redirected image link in R?

Tags: r, image, web-scraping, redirect

Example link: http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/252437.html?alt=1

I tried download.file() and getURL() methods, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
library(httr)
img <- httr::GET("http://www.espncricinfo.com/inline/content/image/252437.html?alt=1")\
writeBin(img$content, "localfile.jpg")
```

You can extract the redirected filename with `img$url`. In this case, you can also find mirrors for it under `img$all_headers`, though that isn't necessarily always the case. Try `str(img)` to see more of the `response` type that `GET` returns.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Thank you so much. Sorry that my upvote isn't reflecting.